# SPOJ ONP - Transform the Expression. Wrong Solution but all test cases given on the website work

Tags: java, postfix-notation

It works for all the test cases as long as the input string has "()" in it. If I input let's say (2+3) or even 2+3) it will print my the correct solution which is 23+. But if I input 2+3 with the parentheses it will just return 23 without the operator.

I don't understand why my last else if statement doesn't work if there is no ')' in the input even though it's a or statement. Can someone tell me what's going wrong here?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str = sc.nextLine();

        sc.close();

        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();

        boolean isLast = false;

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (i == str.length() - 1) {
                isLast = true;
            }
            boolean isLetterOrDigit = Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i));

            if (isLetterOrDigit) {
                stb.append(str.charAt(i));

            } 
            
            else if (!isLetterOrDigit || isLast) {

                if (str.charAt(i) != '(' && str.charAt(i) != ')') {

                    stack.push(str.charAt(i));
                    System.out.println("Operator being pushed " + str.charAt(i));
                }

                else if (str.charAt(i) == ')' || isLast) {
                    System.out.println("Last conditional works which is either a ) or is the last element");
                    while (!stack.empty()) {
                        stb.append(stack.pop());

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println(isLast);
        System.out.println(stb.toString());
    }
```

Also, it would be great if someone could tell me how does spoj tests code? I have several programs that give the correct output when I run them on locally but same programs give wrong solutions on spoj,

Comment: Did you try `else if ((str.charAt(i) == ')') || isLast) {`?

Comment: what's the difference? I tried it and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

If the last character is a letter or digit, you never reach that "last conditional" to see if it is the last.  Using a debugger to watch the execution would make crystal clear as to why.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that. Thanks!